# How to clearfix absolutely positioned elements?

Tags: html, css, less

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rUQ2z/)

[image]

The title appears overtop of the content above it.

Adding the Twitter's `.clearfix` to the container doesn't seem to solve the problem. I'm not sure how to push my titlebar down below the content above it.

Suggestions?

---

`.clearfix` reference (from Twitter Bootstrap) -- written in `less`:

```
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
  &:before,
  &:after {
    display: table;
    content: "";
    // Fixes Opera/contenteditable bug:
    // http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/#comment-36952
    line-height: 0;
  }
  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

And use like:

```
.title-tabs {
  .clearfix;           /* HERE */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #91b6eb;
  position: relative;
  h3 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* etc... */
```

Comment: What css properties have you setted on the `clearfix` class?

Comment: @FelipeOriani: That's ripped straight from Twitter Bootstrap. See update.

Comment: AFAICS this uses the SASS syntax

Comment: Clearing has nothing to do with z-index stacking of elements positioned relatively or absolutely.

Comment: @TimMedora the fiddle works fine ( Panels > scss ), and it's using SASS

Comment: @jerome.s - cool. Didn't know that option existed.

Comment: @jerome.s: `less` actually, but I figured it was close enough to `scss` that jsfiddle could handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is probably what you are looking for

http://jsfiddle.net/rUQ2z/2/

```
    <div class="main-content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="access-details">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <div>Logged in: <b>John Doe</b>
        </div>
        <div>Access Lvl: Noob</div>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <div>Sunday, January 13th, 2013</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title-tabs clearfix">
      <h3>Client Details</h3>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Details</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Program</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Special</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Docs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Notes</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <p>Welcome to Client Details</p>
  </div>
</div>

h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
  &:before, &:after {
    display: table;
    content:"";
    // Fixes Opera/contenteditable bug: // http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/#comment-36952 line-height: 0;
  }
  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }
}
.title-tabs {
  .clearfix;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #91b6eb;
  position: relative;
  h3 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  ul {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    li {
      float: left;
      a {
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 5px;
        background-color: #f9fafe;
        .border-radius(5px, 0, 0, 5px);
        border-color: #91b6eb;
        border-width: 2px 2px 0 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    }
    li + li {
      margin-left: -2px;
    }
  }
}
```

There is no need for position: absolute on the same class that uses float.  You either use floats or you use position relative/absolute.

You want to apply clearfix to the container that contains your float which will update the height of your container allowing the content below the clearfix to not overlap with your content above.

**EDIT**

If you are looking for an alternative answer dealing with dynamic content where you want the menu items to float right and and align bottom then tables is a way to do this.

Take a look at the following code.  I made the container be the table, title-tabs be the title-row and I added ul-container so I can make the menu items be contained within a table cell.

http://jsfiddle.net/rUQ2z/11/

```
<div class="main-content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="access-details">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <div>Logged in: <b>John Doe</b>
        </div>
        <div>Access Lvl: Noob</div>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-right">
        <div>Sunday, January 13th, 2013</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title-tabs">
      <h3>Client Details</h3>
      <div class="ul-container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Details</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Program</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Special</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Docs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Notes</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>Welcome to Client Details</p>
  </div>
</div>

h3 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
  &:before, &:after {
    display: table;
    content:"";
    // Fixes Opera/contenteditable bug: // http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/#comment-36952 line-height: 0;
  }
  &:after {
    clear: both;
  }
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.title-tabs {
  .clearfix;
  display: table-row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #91b6eb;
  position: relative;
  h3 {
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: table-cell;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  .ul-container {
     display: table-cell;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  }

  ul {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    li {
      float: left;
      a {
        display: block;
        padding: 3px 5px;
        background-color: #f9fafe;
        .border-radius(5px, 0, 0, 5px);
        border-color: #91b6eb;
        border-width: 2px 2px 0 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    }
    li + li {
      margin-left: -2px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you just take off the absolute positioning? The reason I had that in there was to bottom-align the tabs, which I can't seem to do otherwise.

Comment: Use margins to do that instead of position absolute.

Comment: You can also use display: table-cell and then use the vertical-align: middle and text-align: left/right if you are dealing with dynamic content.

Comment: I was trying to use `table-cell` but that only caused more problems.

Comment: Regarding your edit, where did the bottom-border go on `.title-tabs`? I need that too :-)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that.  You cannot apply a border to table rows but you can to table cells.  So the solution is to apply a border to each table cell.  Here is a fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/rUQ2z/13/  I changed your border to the following > * { border-bottom: 1px solid #91b6eb; }

Comment: I replaced display: inline-block with float: right in the ul selector in the css and it worked.  http://jsfiddle.net/rUQ2z/15/

Comment: Nice! Thank you for all your effort!

Answer (score 1):

What happened is that your .title-tabs was set to relative, and h3 set to absolute and bottom, because you the .title-tabs do not have a height, so the h3 element will take the last bottom and goes out of the .title-tabs line. Remove bottom from h3 css.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In theory though, the tabs could be taller than the `h3` in which case I'd want the `h3` bottom-aligned, so removing it less than ideal.